# Handling DB queries and filtering Django and Unicode

Tags: python, sql, django, object, unicode

I'm filtering with the following query

```
list = AboutMe.objects.order_by('MyLinkedInLastName').filter(Q(MyGender__contains=Gender1))
```

But it doesn't seem to work when I use the unicode string. Let me explain. In the table, the data field is stored as: `[u'_M', u'_F']` for example. And picking up a row and field of another record might be [u'_M'] for example. When I strip this to the text - i.e. remove [] and display I get u'_M' and I use this as say Gender1 in the filter. Now this doesn't seem to work. But works if I hard code '_M' into the filter. I don't understand what is going on - is there some kind of implicit conversion going on here?

I get Gender1 from `Gender1 = GenderField.split()[0].strip('[],')`

This appears to work however

```
list = AboutMe.objects.order_by('MyLinkedInLastName').filter(Q(MyGender__contains='_M'))
```

BTW I have simplified the Query for the purposes here. It seems to be an issue with encoding. What is the best way to make this work well and robustly?

Comment: Can you post sql dump of the first query?

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the data as a string which is created from the Python representation of a list. This is an extremely bad idea.

The immediate problem is that even once you have remove the `[` characters and split on the comma, what you have left are the *strings* `"u'_M'"` and `"u'_F'"` - that is, the `u` characters and the opening and closing quotes are being stored as part of the string. So this isn't "a Unicode string" as you think, but simply a string that contains a leading `u` followed by quotes.

Instead of doing this, you could perhaps store your text as JSON - there are various implementations around of JSONFields in Django, which take care of serializing and deserializing your data for you.

Comment: Thanks. After I clean the data, is there a cheap / simple way to parse the lists before saving. I'm keen to keep Django as vanilla as possible as I don't know what the eventual platform will be (i.e. might be Google App Engine).

Comment: I did think my method was the canonical way of doing it.